# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, android-theme

I saw a lot of related post in stackoverflow about this message, but it didn't answer my doubts.

In the manifest.xml, I have :

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

So in the posts, they say because my minSdkVersion is 9, I can't use Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.

But it is a nonsense because the default folder values-v14 is only for API 14+ users...

So why do I get this error, I want to maintain my android:minSdkVersion = 9. It should be possible no???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused between the resource folder system and the actual Android version range in which your app is supported. When you declare `android:minSdkVersion="9"` on the `AndroidManifest.xml` you are stating that your app should be able to run on API 9+.

The Android resource structure was stablished to allow developers to use different resources depending on the resolution, screen size, and Android version (among other things) a given device is running. You still need to respect what your `minSdkVersion` is set to; in your case it is 9.`Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` was introduced on API 11, so you cannot use that style since it was not present in API 9.

To give you an example, trying to use `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` when your `minSdkVersion` is 9 is like trying to get a reference of the `ActionBar` when your `minSdkVersion` is 9 (assuming you are not using the support library). Both of these features were not added until a later API; they were not part of Android, they didn't exist.

Comment: ahhhhh ! I didn't see the reference to actionBar. So now I understand... I need to implement support libs ! Tx for helping !